# Javascript conditionals not working on correct button combination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 if else conditions under function `getRadioButtonValue`. The function does not go through all the conditions even after clicking the right button combinations.

I have tried to debug the script using Chrome Developer tools but the problem still exists. Where is the code breaking?

Some information regarding the page, I am using Javascript to hide the div's and headers so that at any one time there is only one question seen.

Only the first if conditions work, but nothing else

The results are seen after `Get Result` button is clicked on the last page which should redirect to the appropriate page.

[DELETED CODE]

[UPDATED CODE]

I am unable to auto hide my div's based on the response given below by Keith. 
FYI: His code works as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 445px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="first-question" class="visible">
  <h3>How?</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>abc</li>
   <li>def</li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-one" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-one" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
  <label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
 </div> 

 <div id="second-question" class="hidden">
  <h3>To</h3>
  <hr>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-two" id="quiz-question-two-yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoYes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-two" id="quiz-question-two-no" value="no" />
  <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoNo">No</label>
 </div>

 <div id="third-question" class="hidden">
  <h3>Make </h3>
  <hr>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-three" id="quiz-question-three-yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeYes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-three" id="quiz-question-three-no" value="no" />
  <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeNo">No</label>
 </div>

 <div id="fourth-question" class="hidden">
  <h3>This</h3>
  <hr>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-four" id="quiz-question-four-yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourYes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-four" id="quiz-question-four-no" value="no" />
  <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourNo">No</label>  
 </div>

 <div id="fifth-question" class="hidden">
  <h3>Work?</h3>
  <hr>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-five-yes" id="quiz-question-five-yes" value="yes" />
  <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveYes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="quiz-question-five-no" id="quiz-question-five-no" value="no" />
  <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveNo">No</label>   
 </div> 

 <div class="page result">
    <label>Results</label>
    <div id="result"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var results = {};

function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if (r.quiz-question-one && r.quiz-question-two && r.quiz-question-three && r.quiz-question-four && r.quiz-question-five) {
     rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if (!r.quiz-question-one && !r.quiz-question-two && !r.quiz-question-three && !r.quiz-question-four && !r.quiz-question-five) {
     rt.text('All No');
  } else {
     rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         page = $this.closest('.hidden'),
         next_page = $(page.next());
     results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
     page.removeClass('visible');
     next_page.addClass('visible');
     if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing, I've just run it and it seems ok.  I answered yes to all 5 questions, and apparently I can now have  Visa,  but it appears you modified your code now, and I can't have a Visa :( anymore.

Comment: @Keith Try doing No to every condition. It does not do anything, And sorry I am trying not to give any information out like that.

Comment: @VuralAcar, I am not sure I understand what you mean, I do get it I have alot of repetition in my code but thats the best way as of now I could figure out as I am new to both CSS and Javascript. I will try to optimize the code in future though

Comment: Only one radio checkbox can ever be selected,.. Radio's are grouped by name, so give each group a name attribute.

Comment: so the downvote is for?

Comment: Javascript devs on stack overflow, the majority are way too quick to jump down peoples throats and downvote if even the smallest of things are wrong, even if what you are sking is clear, dont take it to heart

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes are due to this: [mcve]. Note especially the "minimal" part. Please try to provide a version of your issue in no more than a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: @Mani Wasn't me who down voted you.  But did giving each group of radio checkbox's a unique name solve your problem?

Comment: @Keith I am sorry but not sure how to combine them into a group and then use them. I have seen examples online on how to put them into a group but how can I use the groups (cdnt find an example online) for conditionals. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: @Mani  you basically give each imput that are part of the same question to have the same name,.. I'll post an answer to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an example below that I think you can work from.  The values from the radio I don't think get updated until you submit, instead I've captured the results in the onclick.  You can now add back you CSS styling etc.  Hope that helps.

```js
var results = {};

function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if (r.q1 && r.q2 && r.q3) {
     rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if (!r.q1 && !r.q2 && !r.q3) {
     rt.text('All No');
  } else {
     rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         page = $this.closest('.page'),
         next_page = $(page.next());
     results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
     page.removeClass('active');
     next_page.addClass('active');
     if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});
```

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}

.page.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page active">
  <div>Question 1</div>
  <label for="q1yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="q1yes" type="radio" name="q1" value="yes">
  <label for="q1no">No</label>
  <input id="q1no" type="radio" name="q1" value="no">
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div>Question 2</div>
  <label for="q2yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="q2yes" type="radio" name="q2" value="yes">
  <label for="q2no">No</label>
  <input id="q2no" type="radio" name="q2" value="no">  
</div>

<div class="page">
  <div>Question 3</div>
  <label for="q3yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="q3yes" type="radio" name="q3" value="yes">
  <label for="q3no">No</label>
  <input id="q3no" type="radio" name="q3" value="no">  
</div>

<div class="page result">
   <label>Results</label>
   <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

```
<input type="radio" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
<label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
<label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
```

In the above you are using type="radio", that means all type="radio" with the same name will group together, and not just these two.  To group together just give them a name on the input.  eg.

```
<input type="radio" name="quiz-question-one" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
<label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="quiz-question-one" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
<label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
```

Above you can see I've given the 2 inputs the name="quiz-question-one", and then for the next question maybe give them a name="quiz-question-two" etc..

On another note, there are lots of places where your code could be simplified, but hopefully this will solve your current problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it still has the same behavior. Still evaluates only 1 condition.

Comment: @Mani  Could you edit you snippet to include this, and we'll work from there.

Comment: Thank you for the code, I highly appreciate the help. A afollow up question though. Is the JQuery all under one function? (getRadioButtonValue)
Where do I put `$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         page = $this.closest('.page'),
         next_page = $(page.next());
     results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
     page.removeClass('active');
     next_page.addClass('active');
     if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});` function

Comment: The $(function() {}), is JQuery way to make sure the DOM is ready, you can split out the code inside there into another function if you wish.  It's possibly not needed here, but for good measure my entry point for jQuery stuff I usually do this out of habit.

Comment: I have tried to implement your code in my own version, but it does not work the same way. Could you please have a look at it and tell me what I am missing. The chrome console does not give any errors

I will update that in the code above

Comment: If you look at my code, I used a class called page & hidden, your code is now looking for just .hidden, well it won't have .hidden class as the first page is .visible.  I personally would keep the .page classes like my example has.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help.