# Conditionals with radio button and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This question has a lot of code but without it, it does not work properly.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823143/javascript-conditionals-not-working-on-correct-button-combination)

Problem: 
I am trying to set conditionals using radio buttons so that selected combination lead to a certain outcome.
I have tired multiple approaches but none of them have been successful so far. A user's response in the previous question works only for that example (which I tried to work with)

The code below does not as expected.

**There are 5 question in total .I am using JQuery hide the divs until each question is answered.
If you click on "Yes" on the first one then anything else, it would give out result as ALL YES.
If you click on "No" on the first one then anything else, it would give out result as ALL No.
In between it gives mixed response as the output.**

If anyone can please guide me how I can fix this. I have read multiple things online, did tutorials but I am not able to reach the desired solution.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
}
header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-right: 650px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 5px;
}

div#main-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#get-justice {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
div#get-justice p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    color: red;
    padding: 40px 40px 4px 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
div#get-justice button {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px 37px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h3 {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
div#first-question {
   text-align: center;
}

ul {
    columns: 2;
    background: #EFDFBC;
 text-align: -webkit-left;
}
li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0px 3px 37px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#oneYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#oneNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-two-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-two-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#twoYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#twoNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-three-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-three-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#threeYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
/*label#threeYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-four-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-four-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fourYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fourYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-five-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-five-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fiveYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fiveYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.clientinfo{
 height:445px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 1px 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
}

button#start {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -272px;
    margin-right: 68px;
}

hr {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 27px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#questionOneBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionTwoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionThreeBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFourBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFiveBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
h1 {
    /* padding: 20px 4px 20px; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
/*
h1 {
    //background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
*/

h1#disclaimerHeader{
 background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

div#disc-container {
    width: 450px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 10px 10px 14px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a#disclaimerLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*.hideHeader{
 display:none;
}*/

p#greenText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#yellowText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#redText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

div#questionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    /* border-color: #EFDFBC; */
    /* top: 153px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 30px; */
    /* padding-top: 30px; */
    margin-top: 163px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    /* width: 650px; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.bkr-header{
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 445px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.visible2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 165px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visible4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 195px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visibleHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.page {
 display: none;
}

.page.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
}

.questions {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 444px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.questions-header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.quiz-questions {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
 <title>Questions</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "quiz-questions">
 <div id="first-question" class="page active">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 1 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionOneBody">
   <h3>First Question</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
   </ul>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="second-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 2 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionTwoBody">
   <h3>Second Questions</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="third-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 3 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionThreeBody">
   <h3>Third Question </h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fourth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFourBody">
   <h3>some question</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fifth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFiveBody">
   <h3>Fourth Question</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="page result">
    <label>Results</label>
    <div id="result"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var results = {};

function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
     rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if (!((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive))) {
     rt.text('All No');
  } else {
     rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         page = $this.closest('.page'),
         next_page = $(page.next());
     results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
     page.removeClass('active');
     next_page.addClass('active');
     if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});
  
</script>
```

Comment: So all you care about is the yes or no of the first question? The others do not matter?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek : No, If I have `YES NO NO YES NO ` It should say `mixed response` where as it output `ALL YES` as response for now.

There are 5 questions but the program just goes off the first response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You had a problem with your labels (you had `<label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoNo">No</label>`, while it should be `<label for="quiz-question-two-no" id="twoNo">No</label>`)
2. The `else if` statement was not correct. If you want to check that all values are false it's not enough to test `(! ((val1) && (val2) && (val3)) )`, because if `val1 == true` and `val2 == false`, you will get `!(true && false)` and it equals true. You must use `!` on each of them, or use `||` instead `(! (val1 || val2 || val3) )`.

Here is the fixed snippet:

```js
var results = {};

function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if ((!r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (!r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All No');
  } else {
    rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}

$(function () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        page = $this.closest('.page'),
        next_page = $(page.next());
    results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
    page.removeClass('active');
    next_page.addClass('active');
    if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
}
header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-right: 650px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 5px;
}

div#main-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#get-justice {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
div#get-justice p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    color: red;
    padding: 40px 40px 4px 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
div#get-justice button {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px 37px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h3 {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
div#first-question {
   text-align: center;
}

ul {
    columns: 2;
    background: #EFDFBC;
 text-align: -webkit-left;
}
li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0px 3px 37px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#oneYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#oneNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-two-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-two-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#twoYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#twoNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-three-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-three-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#threeYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
/*label#threeYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-four-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-four-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fourYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fourYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-five-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-five-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fiveYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fiveYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.clientinfo{
 height:445px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 1px 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
}

button#start {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -272px;
    margin-right: 68px;
}

hr {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 27px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#questionOneBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionTwoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionThreeBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFourBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFiveBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
h1 {
    /* padding: 20px 4px 20px; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
/*
h1 {
    //background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
*/

h1#disclaimerHeader{
 background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

div#disc-container {
    width: 450px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 10px 10px 14px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a#disclaimerLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*.hideHeader{
 display:none;
}*/

p#greenText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#yellowText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#redText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

div#questionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    /* border-color: #EFDFBC; */
    /* top: 153px; */
    /* padding-bottom: 30px; */
    /* padding-top: 30px; */
    margin-top: 163px;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    /* width: 650px; */
    /* text-align: center; */
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.bkr-header{
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 445px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.visible2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 165px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visible4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 195px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visibleHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.page {
 display: none;
}

.page.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
}

.questions {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 444px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.questions-header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.quiz-questions {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
 <title>Questions</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "quiz-questions">
 <div id="first-question" class="page active">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 1 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionOneBody">
   <h3>First Question</h3>
   <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
   </ul>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="second-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 2 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionTwoBody">
   <h3>Second Questions</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-no" id="twoNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="third-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 3 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionThreeBody">
   <h3>Third Question </h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-no" id="threeNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fourth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFourBody">
   <h3>some question</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-no" id="fourNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fifth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFiveBody">
   <h3>Fourth Question</h3>
   <hr>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-no" id="fiveNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div class="page result">
    <label>Results</label>
    <div id="result"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have looked through that so many times and I am not sure how every time I missed that. 
Thank you for the note on negation part.